# Does a Rogue's Blindsense let them fully perceive an obscured creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue

At 14th level, a Rogue gains the [Blindsense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Blindsense-350) feature, which states the following:

> if you are able to hear, you are aware of the location of any hidden or invisible creature within 10 feet of you.

Does 'aware of the location' mean that a Rogue knows which square to attack, or can they fully perceive the creature and thus not be subject to a Disadvantage on their attack roll? Previous editions made a distinction on the difference between Blindsense and Blindsight; however, Blindsense doesn't appear to be as clearly defined in the MM as it was previously.

For example, against a creature with the Blur effect, does the Rogue have Disadvantage on the attack or does their Blindsense feature cancel the Disadvantage? What about if the creature is invisible?

To distinguish the difference between the other question, note that the cited spells typically impose Disadvantage on attacks made against them. This question relates specifically to whether that Disadvantage is still applicable for a Rogue with Blindsense.

Comment: Part 1: [How does the Rogue's Blindsense handle obstructions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110659/how-does-the-rogues-blindsense-handle-obstructions)

Comment: In that, there really is nothing different between what you're asking here and what you're asking in the other question.   You seem to have a separation in mind, but reading the two questions, it feels like the same question and it isn't clear how answering the other doesn't also answer this and vice versa.

Comment: Isn't the first question "does Blindsense work through walls", and this question is "does Blindsense remove disadvantage when attacking invisible foes"? Those seem distinct to me.

Answer (score 11):

## Blindsense doesn't remove disadvantage in these cases.

> **When you attack a target that you can’t see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll**. This is true whether you’re guessing the target’s location or you’re targeting a creature you can hear but not see. If the target isn’t in the location you targeted, you automatically miss, but the DM typically just says that the attack missed, not whether you guessed the target’s location correctly.

(PHB, pp. 194-195, "Unseen Attackers and Targets").

Blindsense doesn't mean you can see invisible opponents; it does mean that you don't need to guess at their locations.

As far as *blur* goes:

> For the duration, any creature has disadvantage on attack rolls against you. An attacker is immune to this effect if it doesn't rely on sight, as with blindsight, or can see through illusions, as with truesight.

Blindsense doesn't remove your reliance on sight, or provide any special abilities to see through illusions, so it doesn't help against *blur*.

Comment: FYI IMO, even if you're wrong and corrected, it can be useful to others to see the back and forth and reasoning (and maybe disagree and reverse the correction).  Don't be ashamed of being wrong, just be humble and learn.  Much of my learning is a result of my mistakes and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, Blindsense has no effect on light obscurement, as you already know the presence and location of a lightly obscured creature.  Heavy obscurement is treated the same as blindness (PHB p.183), and so Blindsense would help, by revealing the presence and location of the heavily obscured creature.

Comment: @Phil_Boncer I don't see how this answer is relevant as the question makes no mention of obscurement.

Answer (score -3):

Well... According to Mike, Mearls, a game designer it does mean that Blindsense removes the disadavantage on attacking an invisible creature and the advantage on being hit by that creature :

https://twitter.com/Reaper05594/status/968513585319239681?s=20

Comment: It should be note that while Mike is one of the lead game designers for D&D 5e, [Jeremy Crawford *was* actually the official voice in rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97294/14878). This is no longer the case, however, [as of 2019’s Sage Advice Compendium](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/14878). So while it can be useful to provide designer tweets/rulings, they don’t really carry much weight around here.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Well, there is no mention about blindsense (I'm talking about blindsense and not blindsight) in the Sage Compendium. So, while many here seem to have a firm opinion about blindsense, it happens that others have another that is at least as valid. Just wanted to point it out.